# Rails 4 routing error 'No route matches [GET] "/project"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I moved my rails project to another computer and I getting this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/project"

Rails.root: /home/user/project
```

I already trying everything and still doesn't work.

My routes.rb is the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :orders
  get 'product_statuses/list'

  resources :customers do
    resources :shipping_addresses
  end

  resources :products do
    resources :product_details do
      resources :product_statuses
    end
    resources :prices
  end

  get 'welcome/index'

end
```

I really need help :( please.

Thanks!

Comment: You have no `/project` route. At what point do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to view a particular product, /product is not a route that will work because there is no way to identify it. Given a product with an id of 1, the routes you have defined work like this:

```
/products/1
/products/1/edit
```

You can get rid of the /products/ segment by providing a blank path on the resource, although there are things to be aware of when occupying the root namespace like this:

```
resources :products, path: '' do
  ...
end
```

This will give you routes like this:

```
/1
/1/edit
```

If you aren't happy with the id being displayed in the url, you can either manually write new routes like this (assuming a product has a name attribute):

```
get '/:name', to: 'products#show'
```

Just be aware that this won't work unless you're enforcing uniqueness on the name attribute.

Another options is to can override the param that is displayed and use the routes you already have:

```
class Product

  def to_param
    name.parameterize
  end

  ...
end
```

This will give you routes like this:

```
/products/foo
/products/darth-vader-marshmallows
```

It would be worth your while to review the Rails routing documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html